# Prevent error_log() messages to be printed to the terminal during tests

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, error-log

As the title states, I'm looking forward to finding a way to prevent the `error_log()` message to be printed in the terminal during my `PHPUnit` tests.

[image]

In the example above, the method under test passes through an error_log('Don\'t show up'), printing its message between the tests.

Is there any way to prevent this behavior, to keep my test log fancy? Also, is there any way to catch the message and test its output? (for the cases where the message isn't a simple string).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there any way to prevent this behavior, to keep my test log fancy? Also, is there any way to catch the message and test its output? (for the cases where the message isn't a simple string).

First of all what you see is not the test log. The error message that is *displayed* is actually on the standard error stream and not the standard output stream. For what you see this makes not much of a difference as the terminal shows both intermixed, logging to file would not log that error message.

This is b/c `error_log()` writes the error message to the configured logfile (PHP's `error_log` ini directive). As Phpunit runs with the CLI version of PHP (on the command-line), this by default is the said standard error stream.

This also contains all needed information to not output to the standard error stream but to capture it, e.g. temporarily for a test:

```
$capture = tmpfile();
$saved = ini_set('error_log', stream_get_meta_data($capture)['uri']);
error_log("Test for this message");
ini_set('error_log', $saved);
var_dump(stream_get_contents($capture));
```

This will provide the contents output via `error_log()` and via a temporary file:

```
string(59) "[06-Jul-2017 12:14:45 Europe/Amsterdam] Test for this message
"
```

The temporary file is removed automatically when the test-case ends.

Answer (score 1):

You can define your own error handler using [`set_error_handler()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php). In the comment [#112881](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php#112881) you can see an example using a callback, that you can adapt for your needs, e.g. log to file, simply ignore or whatever.

You can put this into your phpunit bootstrap-file and that should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the correct path of your log file which have enough write permission for your script.

you can set error log file path as below:

```
ini_set("error_log", "log_file_name.log");
```

You can give absolute path like

```
/tmp/logs/script_output.log
```

or relative path as well.